# How can you tell a Root Site Collection was restored? And when?

Tags: migration, restore, bug-fix

We are consultants developing and migrating from SP 2010 to SP 2013. Another supplier are responsible for maintaining servers, guarding memory, processor, disk space and the like.

We don't have access to the SQL Server. But we have a feeling that several root site collections was restored since previous bug fixes came back independently on different web apps.

**How can you tell a Root Site Collection was restored? And when?**

Comment: Are those bug fixes part of custom code solution deployment?

Comment: @404 yes they are. Both simple JavaScripts and more advanced custom Timer Jobs

Comment: So if fixes came back through deployment, you can check the last modified time of WSP - solution file from central admin.

Comment: I think their is one entry for every restore writen in Event Log under Applications And services log > MSFT> sharepoint....check it their...Is site collections restored compeltely?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes. The entire web application. Or More exactly - two different Web Apps... It's suspicious when two isolated web apps fails at the same time with errors previously solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the last modified date of Solution File to which the recent fixes correspond to.

- Go to central admin site
- Click on System Settings
- Click on "Manage Farm Solutions"
- Click on the solution you are interested.
- Check the last operation time